# Access user/userId inside a function called by a publish

Tags: meteor

I have a `Meteor.publish` in my code, that calls another function, that calls another one, and so on. Then, in the most inner function, I need to know what *user* is the active one.

`Meteor.user()` can't be used. It says

> Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions.

and `this.userId` is not acessible inside the inner function.

What can be done then?

Comment: Meteor.publish(null, function(){ self = this; doSomething() { self.userId }});

Comment: the inner functions are declared outside the outer ones

Comment: The exact same question could be asked for this.userId in methods. Clearly something that is not optimal in Meteor.

Answer (score 4):

Can't you just assign `this.userId` to a variable within the publish method and then pass that variable around?

```
Meteor.publish("my_channel", function() {
  var userId = this.userId;
  myFunction(userId);
});
```

Comment: Passing userId, which *is* a global variable, as a parameter of multiple nested function calls is painful and error prone. Hence the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it like this `Reflect.apply(Meteor.call, this, ['myFunctionName'])`